# Does Windows 8 store apps support MS Access database?

Tags: .net, database, c#-4.0, windows-8, ms-access-2007

I have just started learning Windows 8 Store app programming and came around a question. Does Windows 8 Store apps support MS Access database ?

If not then which all database does it support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your definition of support, you could create a WCF service that allows you to access your data from MS Access, see the link below for how to access WCF Services in a Windows store app.

[Accessing WCF Services with a Windows Store Client App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But if you don't want to be tied to MS Access or want to use a database as local storage for the application then here is an article discussing the various options you have for data storage.

[Data Access and Storage Options in Windows Store Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991982.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use SQLite for Windows Store apps.